# Connection to Azure postgres server fails in spite of correct username

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-database-postgresql

When trying to connect to my postgres server in Azure from psql client, I get the following error, even though I am using the correct username. How can I fix this?

*psql: FATAL:  Invalid Username specified. Please check the Username and retry connection. The Username should be in `<username@hostname>` format.*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As noted in the error text, you are required to follow the `<username@hostname>` format when trying to connect to postgresql server, whether you are doing it from psql client or using pgadmin. Using `<username@hostname>` format instead of just `<username>` should get rid of the error.

Read the quick-start documents for [Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/quickstart-create-server-database-portal) and [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/quickstart-create-server-database-azure-cli) to understand more about how to create and configure your postgres server.

Comment: The @ sign in username works fine for objects but not connect strings. According to URI RFC-3986 username allows hex encoding. So replace the @ with %40. user@host:pw@fullhost becomes user%40host:pw@fullhost

Comment: @KevinBurandt, you should add your comment as an answer,

Comment: As of May 5th 2023, this is still the case - `postgresql://username@hostname:pw@hostname:port/dbname`. The hostname will appear twice when using this as a connection string to sqlalchemy's `create_engine`

Answer (score 12):

The @ sign in username works fine for objects but not connect strings. According to URI RFC-3986 username allows hex encoding. So replace the @ with %40. user@host:pw@fullhost becomes user%40host:pw@fullhost

Comment: I think this is the right answer, it worked on my end

Answer (score 0):

In general, I have concluded that while trying to connect into PostgreSQL, you need to follow this username pattern: username@hostname. For newer versions of postgresql (after v11) this is not prerequisite and you can use only  as per documents. But the word prerequisite, I think is wrong, as for every PostgreSQL v15 the username must be . Finally if the host is localhost, the username should be  even for older versions.